# R: Generate dataframe from unnamed list of vectors with name-columns from vector names

Tags: r, apply, purrr

*Edit: it seems clear that the whole scenario is simply to entangled to be solved properly, and the real problem lies in the piece of code that creates a bunch of objects without also naming them. Sorry for the inconvenience, I leave the whole thing up in case anybody runs into the same problem somewhere, sometime.*

Assume I have a list of vectors, like

```
a<-c(1); b<-1:3; c<-1:1000
L <- list(a, b, c)
```

I would like to combine all these vectors into one dataframe and add a column that contains the names of the vectors from which the values originated. One approach would be

```
> tibble(x=c(a, b, c), name=rep(c("a", "b", "c"), times=c(1, 3, 1000)))
# A tibble: 1,004 x 2
       x name 
   <dbl> <chr>
 1     1 a    
 2     1 b    
 3     2 b    
 4     3 b    
 5     1 c    
 6     2 c    
 7     3 c    
 8     4 c    
 9     5 c    
10     6 c    
# ... with 994 more rows
```

however, I have more than three vectors and want to be more flexible than manually having to put the vector names in strings everytime I change one vector. Also, the list is not named to begin with.

How could I put this into a function that accepts any list of vectors and returns the dataframe as requested? Any approach - be it to generate a list of strings from a list of objects, create a properly named list from just the objects, or directly working with `purrr::map()` or some form of `apply()`, would be welcome.

Note: what I mean with a `map()`-approach would be, for example, something like

```
map_dfr(list(a, b, c), ~tibble("x"=x, "name"={{ x }}))
```

and would probably use some sort of quasi-quotation. This example does of course not work as intended.

Comment: if you would have a lot of objects floating around to be coerced into a dataframe, maybe it's better to think about how to put them into a list first?

Comment: The objects in the list actually come from a badly implemented serialisation of a bootstrapping process... I know it's not ideal, but my fear is that to write the bootstrapping into a function might take me more time than putting them together this way.

Comment: Tough to imagine the scenario, but something like this `vars = grep("[a-z]",ls(),value=TRUE) ; map_dfr(vars,~data.frame(value = get(.x),name=.x))`

Comment: You need some way to pull out all the objects, then something like the above with `get()` , again, I think this is a huge mess

Comment: @StupidWolf I agree, it is a huge mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer**

Given a number of variables, exploit `sys.call`:

```
fun <- function(...) {
  n <- sapply(sys.call()[-1], as.character)
  L <- list(...)
  names(L) <- n
  ldply(names(L), function(x) data.frame(x = L[[x]], name = x))
}

str(fun(a, b, c))
```

Output:

```
'data.frame':   1004 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x   : num  1 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 6 ...
 $ name: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
```

Comment: Works for named list, but not for unnamed lists. I will readily admit that the scenario is stupid to begin with, that is on me, but I currently have an unnamed list. If there is an way to create a named list from just the objects though?

Comment: @Lukas I edited the answer. I think this should cover your case.

Answer (score 2):

case when list of names is not there, you may create an object like this before creation of list

```r
rm(list = ls())
a<-c(1); b<-1:3; c<-1:10
nm <- ls()
my.list <- list(a, b, c)

library(tidyverse)

map2_dfr(my.list, nm, ~ .x %>% as.data.frame() %>%
           setNames('x') %>% mutate(name = .y))
#>     x name
#> 1   1    a
#> 2   1    b
#> 3   2    b
#> 4   3    b
#> 5   1    c
#> 6   2    c
#> 7   3    c
#> 8   4    c
#> 9   5    c
#> 10  6    c
#> 11  7    c
#> 12  8    c
#> 13  9    c
#> 14 10    c
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

For unnamed list

```r
a<-c(1); b<-1:3; c<-1:10
my.list <- list(a, b, c)

library(tidyverse)

map2_dfr(my.list, c('a', 'b', 'c'), ~ .x %>% as.data.frame() %>%
           setNames('x') %>% mutate(name = .y))
#>     x name
#> 1   1    a
#> 2   1    b
#> 3   2    b
#> 4   3    b
#> 5   1    c
#> 6   2    c
#> 7   3    c
#> 8   4    c
#> 9   5    c
#> 10  6    c
#> 11  7    c
#> 12  8    c
#> 13  9    c
#> 14 10    c
```

---

For named list

```r
a<-c(1); b<-1:3; c<-1:20
my.list <- list(a = a, b = b, c= c)

library(tidyverse)

imap_dfr(my.list, ~ .x %>% as.data.frame() %>%
       setNames('x') %>% mutate(name = .y))
#>     x name
#> 1   1    a
#> 2   1    b
#> 3   2    b
#> 4   3    b
#> 5   1    c
#> 6   2    c
#> 7   3    c
#> 8   4    c
#> 9   5    c
#> 10  6    c
#> 11  7    c
#> 12  8    c
#> 13  9    c
#> 14 10    c
#> 15 11    c
#> 16 12    c
#> 17 13    c
#> 18 14    c
#> 19 15    c
#> 20 16    c
#> 21 17    c
#> 22 18    c
#> 23 19    c
#> 24 20    c
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

Or

```
a<-c(1); b<-1:3; c<-1:10
my.list <- list(a, b, c)
names(my.list)
library(tidyverse)

map2_dfr(my.list, names(my.list), ~ .x %>% as.data.frame() %>%
           setNames('x') %>% mutate(name = .y))
```

Comment: As I also commented on Laterow: this works for named list, but not for unnamed lists. I will readily admit that the scenario is stupid to begin with, that is on me, but I currently have an unnamed list. If there is an way to create a named list from just the objects though?

Comment: I edited answer for both named and unnamed lists, check it please.

Comment: Yes, the first solution technically solves it; however, I then have to add in the names of the objects manually, which I want to avoid.

Comment: As others pointed out, the whole thing is not really viable to begin with, and I need to change how I created the objects. I have accepted the earlier answer as answer.

Comment: In that case, you may store name of all objects in an object before creating the list, and use that object instead.  See edit